# Why aren't my means plotting on my box plot?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a boxplot with points for the means but the code I'm running just makes the boxplot. What am I doing wrong? Also is it possible to move the x-label over without also shifting the y-label? Thanks!

```
par(las = 1, mar=c(4, 6, 1, 1))
boxplot(Sepal.Length~Species, 
data = iris, 
xlab = 'Species',
ylab = 'Sepal Length', 
horizontal = TRUE)
means <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,mean)
points(means,col="red",pch=18)
```

Answer (score 3):

In short, because `points` requires `x` and `y` arguments and they need to be numeric.

```r
points(x=means, y=seq_along(means), col="red", pch=18)
```

Comment: FYI a safer/more generalizable way may to be to put `seq_along(means)` in place of `1:3`

Comment: @jpsmith good point.  That is better and more idiomatic.